# Custom ListView will replace already existing Listview

Tags: sugarcrm

I have built an addon and that has custom listview for Contacts module.
The filepath is /custom/modules/Contacts/views/view.list.php.This file has listViewProcess() function with my custom code.
Installing the addon will copy this file.
But if someone already had this file it will be replaced.
How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, you can't automatically overwrite and respect the existing file at the same time. Your best bet is probably to use a pre_execute script to display a warning/explanation of what is happening to that file. If you're planning to support Sugar's OnDemand service, that's about all you can do. If you're CE-only or not worried about OnDemand, though, you could use a file_exists check and adjust your warning or abort mission, maybe even back-up the existing file.

Comment: Thanks Matthew that was a great suggestion.However I created a pre_execute script with a die statement still it copies the file.Any Suggestions.